# MYSQL and PHPMYADMIN Error

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm new here and totally new to ubuntu. Though, i have been using 14.01LTS for few weeks, but i wanted to upgrade to 16.04LTS. I started the upgrade, but i had some power issues. After i brought my PC back on, i discover that the X-Server wasn't installed. I learnt a little CLI command and was able to get my UI to work.

But the problem now is, i cant get my phpmyadmin/Apache/mysql-server to work. I have been on it for.

Localhost loads Apache Ubuntu Default Page 
Localhost/php.info -- page not found
Localhost/phpmyadmin [image]

please help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's something wrong with your PHP version.
Try this:

```
# sudo apt-get update 
# sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7
```